# How to capture a URL parameter every time the page loads

Tags: php, jquery, mysql, url

I am trying to do this: I arrive to a website that reads http://www.example.com?wed=123

I am trying to get the last parameter `wed = 123`, then
send it to my db table, after that, if they reach the same page it will say, welcome back, but if it is a different number, make another entry to the table.
This is what I have so far:

```
<form action="phpfile.php">
<input type="hidden" id="day" name="day" value="<?php echo $_GET['wed']; ?>">
<button class="btn greenbtn" type="submit" id="submit">Submit</button>
</form>
```

with jQuery I am passing the value to the PHP that inputs the data into the table:

```
<scrpt>
  $('#submit).click(function(){
   var day = $('#day').val();
   $.post("http://localhost/entries.php",
   {
    day:day
 },
function(data,status){
  alert("Data: " + data + "\nStatus: " + status);
 });
});
```

Now that I get that I will also like to get other numbers from the `?wed=123` url and enter it in an existing database table, I want my table to look like this without entering another user name but if another username is entered I want it to register as user = yo or something else.

```
 ____________________________
 | ID   |   day   |  user   |
 ----------------------------
 | 1    |   123   |  me     |
 ____________________________
 | 2    |   1234  |  me     |
```

then in another database table I would like to enter the `SUM()` of the day, basically the total of the added entries from the previous table. this is where I am at. I don't want to JOIN them, I would like to populate the table with the sum of the other table column.

Comment: Okay, so do you have a specific question/issue?

Comment: why don't you just add the column in your existing table as the `datetime` type and in query you can get the sum of each day no need to create another table just for the sum of daily visitors

Answer (score 0):

I've solved my question. I got the sum of day with a query like this: SELECT SUM(day) WHERE user = 'me'. that gave me back what I wanted.